# MySQL: How to create a mapping between two tables in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, database, join, many-to-many

I have two relevant tables:

Trainee and Device

Each trainee needs to do a training with the device, in order to be allowed to use it. As a trainee needs to be trained in multiple devices and one single device can be used by multiple users I have created a many-to-many relationship between those two.

MySQLWorkbench therefore created me another table which is called 'trainee_has_device' and holds a foreign key to trainee.Id and a foreign key to device.Id.

So far, so good.

I need to get the training status for a trainee to a specific device, so I added a property TrainingStatus on 'trainee_has_device'. My tables then look like this:

```
|trainee|             
--------------------- 
id 
surname
```

---

```
|device|
---------------------
id
deviceName
```

---

```
|trainee_has_device|
---------------------
traineeId
deviceId
TrainingStatus
```

I need to get the training value of every person to every device even if there is no entry in 'trainee_has_device' (if so I would like to get null)

My query looked like this:

```
SELECT * FROM trainee LEFT OUTER JOIN trainee_has_device ON trainee_has_device.traineeId = trainee.id LEFT OUTER JOIN device ON device.id = trainee_has_device.deviceId
```

But Unfortunately I did only get entries which were listed in trainee_has_device or null.

How can I get the TrainingStatus of every person to every device even if there is no entry in 'trainee_has_device'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working with a subquery:

```
SELECT trainee.id as TraineeId, trainee.Prename, trainee.Surname, trainee.Mail, trainee.Department,
trainee.Telephone, device.Name as DeviceName, (SELECT IF (trainee_has_device.trainee_id = trainee.id AND
trainee_has_device.device_id = device.id, trainee_has_device.TrainingStatus, 'N/A')
FROM trainee_has_device WHERE trainee_has_device.trainee_id = trainee.id AND device.id = trainee_has_device.device_id) AS TrainingStatus
FROM trainee JOIN device ORDER BY trainee.Surname, trainee.id, device.Name ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to get the training value of every person to every device even if there is no entry in 'trainee_has_device'

This doesn't make sense, the trainee_has_device table has to be filled first or it won't show you any data. In real world, all of the trainees has to be assigned a set of devices with a default status (New,Familiar...) for each assignment. So if the connection isn't available between Trainee A and Device C it just means that Device C isn't assigned to Trainee A

Comment: Okay I guess I understand what you mean. But look with this approach: If I want to insert a new trainee and my device table is filled with 4 devices I would have to make another 4 inserts in trainee_has_device table. I honestly don't know, but isn't that bad practice?

Comment: @BigPenguin hmm, If you didn't have the TrainingStatus for every trainee -device pair I would have recommended you to avoid creating a many to many table and just do a join to get all of the trainee with all available devices. That is if you don't intend to selectively assign certain devices to certain Trainees. But since you need to store a unique status for every Trainee-Device pair, you will have to fill that record for every entry to save that initial status